# My localStorage result displayed [null,null,"something"]] instead of "something"

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

My problem is that the result display is `[null,null,"something"]]` instead of `"something"`.

My code looks like this:

```
var simpan = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('subject')) || [];
                        simpandata.push(subjek);
                        localStorage.setItem('subject', JSON.stringify(simpandata));

var showsubjek = localStorage["subject"];
        showsubjek = JSON.stringify(showsubjek);
        showsubjek2 = JSON.parse(showsubjek);
        document.getElementById("getItemitu").innerHTML=showsubjek2;
```

Then if i remove this code : `showsubjek = JSON.stringify(showsubjek);`
The result would be displayed `[object, object]...`

Answer (score 1):

Get the `localStorage` value as shown below (**Correct way**).

**Wrong way**

```
var showsubjek = localStorage["subject"];
```

**Correct Way**

```
var showsubjek = localStorage.getItem("subject");
```

Comment: here is the list of all functions of Storage object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage